macvlan inaccessible to outside devices even with ip routes
I'm trying to setup a docker container that will be accessible to the network with a mac address and a static IP. I'm using macvlan for that
First I've created the network in docker
docker network create -d macvlan \
    --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 \
    --gateway=192.168.1.1 \
    --ip-range=192.168.1.64/26 \ # To avoid overlapping with current devices
    -o parent=wlp0s20f3 \ # My wifi connection
    macvlan

Then I've configured the routes on my host machine (running ubuntu) with:
sudo ip link set wlp0s20f3 promisc on
sudo ip link add dockerrouteif link wlp0s20f3 type macvlan mode bridge
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.249/32 dev dockerrouteif
sudo ip link set dockerrouteif2 up
sudo ip route add 192.168.1.64/26 dev dockerrouteif

And ran the container using docker compose
services:
  app:
    ...
    networks:
      macvlan:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.100
        aliases:
          - app.external
    ...
networks:
  macvlan:
    external: true
    name: macvlan

This works, the container can access my network devices, my host can access the IP 192.168.1.100 but I can't ping that machine from outside the host
I've disabled firewalls, checked iptables to see if anything is blocking access and after a lot of digging I got this from arp -n and I don't know how to proceed:
? (192.168.1.100) at <incomplete> on wlp0s20f3

In all of the documentation, articles, tutorials, guides and videos, macvlan "just works" and I can't find what I am doing wrong

I need to mention that docker macvlan is inaccesible but in the same host I have a virtualbox machine with an ip 192.168.1.6 and a MAC address 08:00:27:8b:47:a2 that I can access from outside hosts

VirtualBox implements "hacks" to make bridging a WLAN station (i.e. a "client") possible (basically doing something that is somewhat similar to source NAT to the MAC addresses). The Linux kernel does not implement such hack, so neither is having MACVLANs on a WLAN interface nor making it a bridge slave is supposed to work, because WLAN standards requires frames to have the same source MAC address as the one advertised in association (with the AP). Frames otherwise is expected to rejected by the AP. (The host/container communication worked does not involve the AP.)
